# pi zero W as remote ethernet jack / internet access for satellite TV receiver

Tags: usb, wireless, pi-zero-w

I've got a pi Zero W that I'd like to use  to support a wireless network for my satellite  TV  tuner.    The tuner has an ethernet  jack, but  running cable to it is  problematic...   I've got a working  wireless network feeding a separate  ROKU device.   I'd like to configure the Zero to connect to the existing  wireless network  and use  a USB ethernet dongle  to provide  internet access to the  receiver. Is the USB network interface  throughput high enough for this kind of application?  The  TV  has  extra HDMI inputs  as well..  so a solution that allows me  to use the zero with bluetooth keyboard and  display a  browser on the TV  might be  nice...

Comment: Kinda depends on what you're doing with your tuner box - have you done any testing to determine how much bandwidth it uses in normal operation?